# CakePHP / MySQL Condition AND / OR Results Output - Logic

Tags: mysql, cakephp, logic

I am trying to modify my query to include record w/ Plan.id == 848 (this is a very specific record I need regardless of other results). So **848 should be included at all times despite and other results**.. I thought a simple AND would solve this, but that query (as I have it below) only includes the 848 in my results. **I tried many variations of AND/OR and cannot get this specific record to be included despite my other query data.**

```
                "OR" => array(
                'AND' => array(
                    $ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'       => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    "NOT"              => array(array('PlanDetail.company_id' => array('27', '3')))),
                array(
                    'Plan.id' => array('848')), // This 848 record should be included with any other results regardless of other query criteria.

                array(
                    $PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'),
                array(
                    $OdsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                    'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                    'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                    'PlanDetail.company_id' => '3'))
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make another database query and combine results manually. It will take like 1 ms more of users time. If that is a problem you can always cache the extra query.

Comment: SOLVED.I just added a new AND limiting the query criteria for any records that belonged to that company.

Answer (score 0):

I would just UNION in the 848 record to the result. Anything else would potentially mess up the ANDs and ORs, or at the very least over-complicate the code.

Comment: I tried several methods to add a UNION, but the 'conditions' and my 'options' can't take that... I can only get inner, left or right joins to work. Can you make a suggestion as to where I should apply the UNION clause?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Then I'd go with @Henri's response. Not really different than mine anyway.